# Insert if doesn't exist - in python+sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

The problem: find an rdbms-independent way to get a value with the specified key from a database using sqlalchemy! If the key doesn't exist, generate a new value and insert it to the table. In a multiuser+multiprocess environment...

I have two ideas:
1st get it, if it returns None, then generate a new and insert, if it is unsuccessful (because of duplicate key) then get it again.

2nd: lock the table, get it, if returns None, then generate a new and insert

The 2nd seems to be better, but I can't find an rdbms-independent solution for locking a table. (session.execute('lock ...') is inappropriate, because it uses sql directly)

The 1st looks... khm... unprofessional.
How can I solve this?

Comment: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Session.merge

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I am not sure what is performance of [merge](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Session.merge), but regarding to [this post](https://devandchill.com/posts/2020/02/postgres-building-concurrently-safe-upsert-queries/) (which I highly recommend) the best option would be to use [upsert](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/postgresql.html#insert-on-conflict-upsert) and then just read from the table

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import insert

insert_stmt = insert(my_table).values(id='id',data='data')
do_nothing_stmt = insert_stmt.on_conflict_do_nothing(index_elements=['id'])
db.query(table).get("id")
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do it one call. It wasn't easy because insert.values(**items) doesn't allow a where clause combined with NOT EXISTS. We need a subquery but then we alson need literals for every column and the keys for the insert.Also the literal for datetime caused a insert issue (formatting, maybe just postgres). I am wondering if there is a better way for the date issue.

In below example item_dict is a dictionary with field: value entries. It is only inserted if the invoice_number AND invoice_line_number don't already exist.

```
    # Create literals for select. Datetime conversion was needed because insert failed without it due to formatting issues.
    literals = [literal(val) if key != 'invoice_date' else literal(val.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")) for key,val in item_dict.items() ]
    
    # NOT exists subquery providing the literals.
    insert_select = select(literals).where(
        ~exists(literal(1)).where(
            (performance_row_table.c.invoice_number == item_dict['invoice_number']) &
            (performance_row_table.c.invoice_line_number == item_dict['invoice_line_number'])
        )
    )

    keys = [key for key in item_dict.keys()]
    # Insert using the subquery
    insert_statement = performance_row_table.insert().from_select(keys, insert_select).returning(performance_row_table)

    compiled = insert_statement.compile(compile_kwargs={"literal_binds": True})
    print(compiled)
    insert_result = session.execute(insert_statement).fetchone()
```